# Can Android tests be developed in Java for a Kotlin application? How about Kotlin tests in a Java application?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-testing

I am very new to test development inside an Android environment and I am trying to figure out if I can use frameworks such as Mockito for test development in Kotlin and this question came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

> Can Android tests be developed in Java for a Kotlin application?

Yes, though you will need to deal with [Java-Kotlin interop concerns](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/interop).

> How about Kotlin tests in a Java application?

That depends on what you mean by "a Java application":

- If you mean an app that is not configured for Kotlin support via Gradle, then you cannot write Kotlin anywhere in that app, whether in tests or anywhere else
- If you mean an app that is configured for Kotlin support but just happens to only have Java code, then yes, you can write tests in Kotlin (with similar interop concerns)

> I am trying to figure out if I can use frameworks such as Mockito for test development in Kotlin

Yes, though frequently there is already a Kotlin wrapper for those things. In the case of Mockito, [`mockito-kotlin`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) works nicely.